# I can flash Cyanogenmod though my bootloader is locked

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-nexus, rom-flashing, clockworkmod-recovery, recovery-mode

I am using a Samsung Galaxy Nexus and CWM as recovery. Even though I locked my bootloader after installing the recovery, I can flash Cyanogenmod 10 using CWM without any errors. Now I am wondering why this works?

When I unpack the Cyanogenmod 10 `.zip` on my computer, there's also a `boot.img`, so I guess it also replaces the bootloader? Maybe when the bootloader is locked, this step is skipped (but no error shown) and the stock ROM bootloader is also OK?

This ends up in my final question: While it works, am I maybe missing a bootloader update when flashing Cyanogenmod while my bootloader is locked?

Comment: The boot.img file is written the `/boot` partition, not the bootloader partition. They're different.

Comment: Thanks! Hmm, then in which case do I actually have to unlock the bootloader? What about changing the recovery, I guess this is also not the bootloader partition?

Comment: Correct, the recovery image exists on a separate partition. From what I know (but I'm not 100% positive) you really only need to unlock the bootloader on the Galaxy Nexus to be able to flash unsigned images via fastboot.